# How to add new key-value pair in MutableData during Firebase Transaction in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to add a new key value pair via transaction in Android. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The `MutableData` object that you get in `doTransaction()` has a `child()` method that you can use to read/write child data.

```
ref.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
  @Override
  public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData currentData) {
    currentData.child("my new child").setValue(1);
    return Transaction.success(currentData);
  }
  @Override
  public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, boolean committed, DataSnapshot currentData) {
    //This method will be called once with the results of the transaction.
  }
});
```